# Legend Not Missing when Creating Chart Using PROC SGPLOT on Grouped Data

Tags: charts, sas, time-series

I'm creating a chart in SAS and for some reason a legend is not being automatically generated.  I have grouped data (titled 'brand') that is going to create about twenty lines of time series data.  I don't want to specify the name and format of every line.  I haven't found a way to avoid explicitly defining and formatting each line.  Is there a way to do this in SAS?

My data has this format:

```
Brand   Time    Sale
A       1       12
A       2       15
A       3       10
A       4       10
B       1       12
B       2       32
B       3       15
B       4       30
C       1       8
C       2       9
C       3       12
C       4       15
```

This is what I have to simply make the chart:

```
proc sgplot data=work.summary;
series x=year y=sale_amt / group=brand;
run;
```

Thank you.

Comment: To clarify, you don't want the default legend that's created, you want a legend customized in the footnote somehow? You need to show us how you want that to appear. Have you looked at the KEYLEGEND statement and options?

Comment: And you need to specify your version of SAS, ie SAS 9.4 TS1M4

Comment: @Reeza, for some reason there is no default legend being created at all.  Maybe I have a default turned off somehow.  All I need is a legend to be created without having to make it manually.  I have been trying different statements and options using KEYLEGEND but haven't had any success.  I have SAS 9.3.  Maybe it has something to do with the grouping?  I'll put a sample of the data up for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS should be creating a legend by default, if it doesn't the log may have a note indicating why it didn't. AFAIK, this works in the latest versions of SAS.

```
proc sgplot data=sashelp.stocks;
series x=date y=open / group=stock;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't think to check the log (poor intuition on my part) because I didn't know that SAS created the legend automatically.  I thought that I was missing an option or somethin to that nature. I found that my chart size was set too small since there were so many groups.  I used this code to increase the size and the problem is solved. `ods graphics / maxlegendarea=40;`  Thank you.